# Custom Ha-proxy on Openshift

Tags: openshift, haproxy

how it's possibile configure ha-proxy of router in order to make a selection on the headers of incoming calls and possibly add other outgoing headers...

I'd like to append a new header only for a call coming from particular hostname or with a specific header

Answer (score 2):

You can get the default haproxy template by [Obtaining the Router Configuration Template](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/router/customized_haproxy_router.html#obtaining-router-configuration-template),

```
# oc get po
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
router-2-40fc3             1/1       Running   0          11d
# oc rsh router-2-40fc3 cat haproxy-config.template > haproxy-config.template
```

and then you can customize the template, such as adding additional header through haproxy configurations. Refer [Go Template Actions](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/router/customized_haproxy_router.html#go-template-actions) for router template details, and refer [http-request set-header](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-http-request) for haproxy config details.

```
# vim haproxy-config.template
```

After customizing, you should replace the template with current one through [Using a ConfigMap to Replace the Router Configuration Template](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/router/customized_haproxy_router.html#using-configmap-replace-template) steps.

```
$ oc create configmap customrouter --from-file=haproxy-config.template
$ oc set volume dc/router --add --overwrite \
    --name=config-volume \
    --mount-path=/var/lib/haproxy/conf/custom \
    --source='{"configMap": { "name": "customrouter"}}'
$ oc set env dc/router \
    TEMPLATE_FILE=/var/lib/haproxy/conf/custom/haproxy-config.template
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

My config file is like this...let's assume we want to add the new header with a value...

So I just need to add the line :  http-request add-header new_header_name:value?

but if I want to add the new header only for a particular hostname in input how I have to do?

```
*frontend public
    
  bind :80
  mode http
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if HTTP
  monitor-uri /_______internal_router_healthz
  # Strip off Proxy headers to prevent HTTpoxy (https://httpoxy.org/)
  http-request del-header Proxy
  # DNS labels are case insensitive (RFC 4343), we need to convert the hostname into lowercase
  # before matching, or any requests containing uppercase characters will never match.
  http-request set-header Host %[req.hdr(Host),lower]
  # check if we need to redirect/force using https.
  acl secure_redirect base,map_reg(/var/lib/haproxy/conf/os_route_http_redirect.map) -m found
  redirect scheme https if secure_redirect
  use_backend %[base,map_reg(/var/lib/haproxy/conf/os_http_be.map)]
  default_backend openshift_default*
```